# Not getting number when crawling number of new COVID cases through BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, apple-m1

Good evening,

I am currently trying to crawl the South Australia's covid case number from the website (https://www.covid-19.sa.gov.au/home/dashboard).

I found the the numbers are under

```
<div id="convid19-data-visual" class="twbs">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row southaus">
        <div clsass="col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="padding:10px 25px">
            <div class="st">
                "New Cases"
                <span class="nCasesa majorNum">64</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thus, I tried to crawl the number by applying the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://www.covid-19.sa.gov.au/home/dashboard")
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
cases = soup.find("div", {"class" : "st"}
st = cases.find_all("span")
print(st)
```

and I got result of

```
[<span class="nCasesa majorNum"> </span>]
```

which does not include the case number.

I had tried with selenium as well, but I was not able to get the case number either. I'm now confused whether the HTML tag that I found is right.

If possible, would it be able to be fixed by getting right HTML tag?

Thanks!

Comment: The line `cases = soup.find("div", {"class" : "st"}` seems to be incomplete, syntax error. edit it please.

Comment: `https://www.covid-19.sa.gov.au/__data/assets/file/0004/145849/covid_19_daily.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text associated with the span element of class nCasesa is loaded dynamically (JavaScript) and there is a delay in rendering the actual value in your browser. What you need to do (with Selenium) is to detect a change to the text. You can do it like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

CLASS = 'nCasesa'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

class detect():
    def __init__(self, locator, params):
        self.locator = locator
        self.params = params
        self.text = None

    def gettext(self, driver):
        return driver.find_element(self.locator, self.params).text

    def __call__(self, driver):
        if self.text is None:
            self.text = self.gettext(driver)
        else:
            current = self.gettext(driver)
            if current != self.text:
                self.text = current
                return True
        return False

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get(f'https://www.covid-19.sa.gov.au/home/dashboard')
    detector = detect(By.CLASS_NAME, CLASS)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(detector)
    print(detector.text)
```

**Output:**

```
73
```

Answer (score 0):

Data comes dynamically from a daily covid_19 data file. You can dynamically pick up this file from one of the covid related js source files. Then request the json data from the daily file

```
import requests, re

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.covid-19.sa.gov.au/configuration/container-templates/data-visualisation/chartdata.js')
    data_url = re.search(r'var dataSource = "(.*?)"', r.text).group(1)
    data = s.get(data_url).json()
    
print(f"{data['hp_date']}: new cases = {data['newcase_sa']}")
```